# Getting started with Hashing for Information retrieval

Tags: ds.data-structures, hash-function, db.databases

I  recently finished my bachelors and now work on Cross-lingual language  search. I want to get started in hashing and see how they are useful  in information retrieval. (Yes, I know what hashing is), but there are so many methods and all of them  sound  pretty fascinating,  so it will be awesome to have a list of resources, which can be referred to,  starting from absolute newbie level to the current state-of-the art.

*Please don't refer me to something like a Knuth because while Knuth is pretty awesome, it is not what i am looking for.*

Comment: You might have more success asking your question on http://metaoptimize.com/qa/, which is devoted to machine learning.

Comment: Thanks, let me try it there.    Yup , i did know about metaoptimize but  i was more hopeful here too :)

Comment: i asked on metaoptimize but i don't think i am gonna get any answers as such :( .  Thanks,  either way.

Comment: (1) Please be specific in why Knuth does not satisfy your needs.  It seems to me that what you really need is a general introduction to data structures, not specifically to hashing, so Knuth seems one of the very appropriate answers.  (2) Please add a link to your crosspost on MetaOptimize.  Hiding the crossposted question is not good.

Comment: 1. I said Knuth only because i need to know about hashing in general and in a concise way and then only know about how hashing is used  in Information retrieval. Knuth is vast and  exhaustive and due to time constraints, i am not  asking for it. 2.  I did not know that not posting the link is bad. Here,  http://bit.ly/efZ5yw

Comment: I do not understand what is the question. (In particular, I see no question mark.)

Answer (score 1):

Probably this may help you. May not cover all but I found this as a great place to start. http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/

Comment: This is about hashing in relation to cryptography, rather than information retrieval.